# Interpreting a logarithmic difference as an error

Tags: measurement-error, logarithm

This is a fairly simple question but I can't figure out which one is the correct approach.

In astronomy it is usual to report age values via their base 10 logarithms instead of the actual value. So a star that is $1\times10^8\,yrs$ old is said to have an age of $\log(age)=8$.

Assume that for a given object I have both its real age, let's say:

$$age_{r} = 1\times10^8\,yrs\; or \; log(age_{r})=8$$

where $r$ stands for "real", and an *estimate* of that age, given exclusively as the logarithm:

$$log(age_{t})=9$$

where $t$ stands for "estimated".

If I interpret the difference between the real and the estimated $\log(age)$ values as a *logarithmic error* in the real age:

$$e_{\log(age_r)} = \Delta \log(age) = log(age_{t}) - log(age_{r}) = 9-8 = 1$$

then I can use the relation:

$$y = \log(x) \Rrightarrow e_y = \frac{e_x}{\ln(10) \times x} \Rrightarrow e_{log(age_r)} = \frac{e_{age_r}}{\ln(10) \times age_r[yrs]}$$

to estimate an error for the real age *in years* as:

$$e_{age_r} = e_{log(age_r)} \times \ln(10) \times age_r[yrs]\simeq 2.3\times10^8\,yrs$$

Conversely, I could estimate an error *in years* simply by taking the difference between the real and the estimated ages *in years*:

$$e_{age_r} = age_t - age_r = 1\times10^9 - 1\times10^8 = 9\times10^8\,yrs$$

The values, as seen, are wildly different.

Where am I going wrong here? Is either of these approaches more valid than the other to the purpose of assigning an error (or uncertainty) to the real age value given the estimated one? Is either valid *at all*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in age is $$1\times10^9\,\mathrm{yrs}-1\times10^8\,\mathrm{yrs}=9\times10^8\,\mathrm{yrs}$$
The error in log age is $$ \log10^9\,\mathrm{yrs} - \log10^8\,\mathrm{yrs}= (9+\log\mathrm{yrs})-(8+\log\mathrm{yrs})=1$$, i.e. a multiplicative error in age of $10^1=10$. Both are correct: the estimated age of one thousand million years is ten times too high *and* nine-hundred million years too high. For statistical modelling the question of interest is whether it's better to assume errors in age or errors in log age have the same distribution for stars of different ages.

What you're doing wrong is using a Taylor-series approximation for small errors when the error is large:

$$e_{\log(\mathrm{age_r})} \approx \frac{e_\mathrm{age_r}}{\ln(10) \times \mathrm{age_r}} \quad\text{when $\mathrm{e_{age_r}}\ll \mathrm{age_r}$}$$

(& you don't really need to use an approximation anyway).